# Parsing XML with namespace in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have following xml in my table. I want to get `ID` of a `fv` node:
`<fv ID="Description">` or not

```
<DataFormItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="bb_appfx_dataforms">
  <Values>
    <fv ID="JobInterval">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">10</Value>
    </fv>
    <fv ID="JobEnabled">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</Value>
    </fv>
    <fv ID="JobName">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Default transactional email process</Value>
    </fv>
    <fv ID="ScheduleFrequencySubDayType">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">2</Value>
    </fv>
  </Values>
</DataFormItem>
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. It would be awesome if you could share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `YourTable` and the XML column is called `XmlData` (adapt and change this to meet your actual situation!), you can try this XQuery code:

```
-- declare the XML namespace as the DEFAULT
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'bb_appfx_dataforms')
    SELECT
        -- extract the value from the <Value> subnode of the <fv> node, if found
        FvValue = XC.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
    FROM
        dbo.YourTable
    CROSS APPLY
        -- get a list of XML fragments - one for each <fv> node
        XmlData.nodes('/DataFormItem/Values/fv') AS XT(XC)
    WHERE
        -- find the XML fragment with the ID="Description"
        XC.value('@ID', 'varchar(50)') = 'Description'
```